# Laravel Mail Queue Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, bulk

I am using queue function of laravel to send email. But I think it is not working because it slow down the page process when sending large emails and do data is being saved in jobs table. I am using following code:

```
Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->queue(new Test($mailContent,$subject));
```

Configuration in queue.php file is:

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],
```

Comment: What QUEUE_DRIVER do you have in your .env file?

Comment: @sisve I have smtp in my .env file

Comment: You have to set queue drive in your env file as this ``QUEUE_DRIVER=database``

Comment: yes thanks @NazmulHasan. It works after changing this. :)